# Borderless Form Resizing Glitch

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, visual-glitch, borderless

I want make borderless form.
My problem is, when I want resize form (on LEFT or TOP side) the form other side is jumping. (See attached gif.)
I try SetWindowPos and WndProc but similar problem.

**Question: How can I resize my borderless form with ResizeRedraw and Doublebuffering without glitch?**

This my simlified code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Public Sub New()
      DoubleBuffered = True
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
      FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
  End Sub
  Dim down As Boolean = False
  Dim _Right As Integer = 0
  Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
      _Right = Right
      down = True
  End Sub
  Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
      If down Then
          Dim xy As Point = PointToScreen(e.Location)
          SetBounds(xy.X - 2, Me.Top, _Right - xy.X - 2, Height)
      End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

[Glitch anim GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZmUY.gif)

OS: Windows 7

Dev: VS 2015, VB, .NET 2.0

Comment: That code works fine for me, you say that is simplified....?

Comment: Yes, simplified, but this simplified code make glitch in form resizing. But I see this glitch all borderless application. e.g. Visual Studio 2015, Sticky Notes.....

Comment: As I said, I copied it as is from above and it works fine. R u sure you do not have something else still active to stretch/move in other directions you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's some C# code based on wndproc.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)

    {
        const int RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE = 10;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x0084/*NCHITTEST*/ :
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if ((int)m.Result == 0x01/*HTCLIENT*/)
                {
                    Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                    Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);
                    if (clientPoint.Y <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)13/*HTTOPLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)12/*HTTOP*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)14/*HTTOPRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)10/*HTLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)2/*HTCAPTION*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)11/*HTRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)16/*HTBOTTOMLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)15/*HTBOTTOM*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)17/*HTBOTTOMRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                }
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x20000; // <--- use 0x20000
            return cp;
        }
    }
```